# What does errno in fs.lstat err variable means?

Tags: linux, node.js

i wrote this sample code to replicate Lstat error.

`var fs=require("fs");
var path="/home/unixroot/Desktop/zookeeper1";
fs.lstat(path,function(err,stats){
        if(err)
        {
                if(err.code==="ENOENT")
                {
                        fs.exists(path,function(exist) {
                        if(!exist)
                                console.log("Path does not exists");
                        });
                }
                console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
        console.log(stats);
        }
});` 

Now i am providing path which does not exists and when i print err variable. it shows like this.

`{ [Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/unixroot/Desktop/zookeeper1']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/unixroot/Desktop/zookeeper1' }`

I am not sure about errno which is 34 in this case. My question is what it means and is there any list of those errno to find out exact cause of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`errno` means "error number" and is just a code number assigned to a particular error on Unix-like systems. Generally, the symbolic version of the code is more useful.

In C, you would use the `strerror` function to convert the code to an actual description. It doesn't seem like node.js includes such a function, but there seem to be some user implementations:

- https://github.com/rvagg/node-errno
- https://www.npmjs.org/package/syserrno

You can also check the manpage for `lstat` or refer to the glibc manual's [section on error codes](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html#Error-Codes).

Comment: Thanks a ton for posting a comment @jjlin. I will look over those links. Apart from that i want to ask one silly question, is the lstat of linux or unix and nodejs fs.lstat does same work and return the identical errors ? because if it is, it will solve my problem at all.

Comment: Yes, if it's named the same, it's almost certainly relying on the underlying OS and libraries to do the work, at least on Unix-like systems.